# shortest word js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите плес, почему не рабоатет?

> Simple, given a string of words, return the length of the shortest
>   word(s).
>
> String will never be empty and you do not need to account for
>   different data types.

```js
function findShort(s) {
  let res = s.split(' ');
  let a;
  for (let i = 0; i < res.lenght; i++) {
    a = Math.min(res[i].length);
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: если что, то результат findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"); //3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны выбрать между длинной текущего слова и наименьшей длинной, встреченной до этого слова `Math.min(res[i].length, a)`.
А вы просто берете длину последнего слова :)

```js
function findShort(s) {
  let res = s.split(' ');
  let a = Infinity;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    a = Math.min(res[i].length, a);
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(findShort("Hello my dear friend"));
```

```js
function findShort(s) {
  return Math.min(...s.split(' ').map(word => word.length));
}

console.log(findShort("hello my dear friend!"));
```

Comment: спасибо большое